# Error in `V<-`(`*tmp*`, value = `*vtmp*`) : invalid indexing

Tags: r, bibliography

I used the bibliometrix function in R, and want to plot some useful graphs.

```
library(bibliometrix)
??bibliometrix
D<-readFiles("E:\\RE\\savedrecs.txt")

M <- convert2df(D,dbsource = "isi", format= "plaintext")
results <- biblioAnalysis(M ,sep = ";" )
S<- summary(object=results,k=10, pause=FALSE)
plot(x=results,k=10,pause=FALSE)
options(width=100)
S <- summary(object = results, k = 10, pause = FALSE)
NetMatrix <- biblioNetwork(M1, analysis = "co-occurrences", network = "author_keywords", sep = ";")

S <- normalizeSimilarity(NetMatrix, type = "association")
net <- networkPlot(S, n = 200, Title = "co-occurrence network",type="fruchterman", labelsize = 0.7, halo = FALSE, cluster = "walktrap",remove.isolates=FALSE, remove.multiple=FALSE, noloops=TRUE, weighted=TRUE)

res <- thematicMap(net, NetMatrix, S)
plot(res$map)
```

But in the  `net <- networkPlot(S, n = 200, Title = "co-occurrence network",type="fruchterman", labelsize = 0.7, halo = FALSE, cluster = "walktrap",remove.isolates=FALSE, remove.multiple=FALSE, noloops=TRUE, weighted=TRUE)`, it shows error

> Error in `V<-`(`*tmp*`, value = `*vtmp*`) : invalid indexing

. Also I cannot do the CR, it always shows unlistCR. I cannot use the NetMatrix function neither.
Some help me plsssssssss

Comment: Please replace the beginning of your code by the output of `dput(S)`, chances that somebody will go through unreproducible code and guess the causes of the error are quite low and your question as is will most likely be closed.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Thanks for your comment, you mean like dput(S)<- normalizeSimilarity(NetMatrix, type = "association")

Comment: no, I meant, just run`dput(S)` before the line that triggers the error, and copy the output to your question

Comment: try `x <- c(1,3,7)` and `dput(x)`, you'll understand what it does

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper thanks, but the same error still exists........

Comment: that's not a way to solve the problem :), that's a way for us to help you, because no one will solve your issue as it's currently presented

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the data itself not in the code you presented. When I downloaded the data from [bibliometrix.com](http://bibliometrix.com) and changed `M1` to `M` (typo?) in `biblioNetwork` function call everything worked perfectly. Please see the code below:

```
library(bibliometrix)

# Plot bibliometric analysis results
D <- readFiles("http://www.bibliometrix.org/datasets/savedrecs.txt")
M <- convert2df(D, dbsource = "isi", format= "plaintext")
results <- biblioAnalysis(M, sep = ";")
S <- summary(results)
plot(x = results, k = 10, pause = FALSE)
```

[image]

```
# Plot Bibliographic Network
options(width = 100)
S <- summary(object = results, k = 10, pause = FALSE)
NetMatrix <- biblioNetwork(M, analysis = "co-occurrences", network = "author_keywords", sep = ";")
S <- normalizeSimilarity(NetMatrix, type = "association")
net <- networkPlot(S, n = 200, Title = "co-occurrence network", type = "fruchterman", 
                   labelsize = 0.7, halo = FALSE, cluster = "walktrap",
                   remove.isolates = FALSE, remove.multiple = FALSE, noloops = TRUE, weighted = TRUE)
```

[image]

```
# Plot Thematic Map
res <- thematicMap(net, NetMatrix, S)
str(M)
plot(res$map)
```

[image: map]

Comment: Can you please explain what is the origin of this error: 
"Error in `V<-`(`*tmp*`, value = `*vtmp*`) : invalid indexing"? I got it for histPlot function.

Comment: Hi, do not see histPlot function in my code, could you elaborate? However, usually such errors are thrown because of violation of formatting / naming conventions (column names in data.frame are not such as intended, or length of data.frame passed is wrong, or some N/As in text or else ). Without details (source code or data) it is difficult to judge.  Additionally 4 years passed, maybe they changed the format.